# OrientDB - On demand time tree node creation

Tags: neo4j, orientdb

Creating a time tree is pretty straight forward in Neo4j:

```
MERGE (y:Year {id:2014})
MERGE (y)<-[:PART_OF]-(m:Month {id:1})
MERGE (m)<-[:PART_OF]-(d:Day {id:13})
RETURN y.id,m.id,d.id;
```

(taken from [jexp.de/blog](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/04/importing-forests-into-neo4j/)).

How do I achieve the same result in OrientDB? It seems to be lacking an equivalent MERGE function (if exist, ignore, else create).

Thanks in advance,

-ifor

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UPDATE ... UPSERT ...](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/SQL-Update.html). Note however this works for vertices, [not edges](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/1114).

Comment: Thanks, so I can do this: `update DAY set time = 10 upsert return after @rid where time = 10` which gives me a new DAY vertex with a value of 10, then return its `@rid`. It seems like it's going to be quite verbose to check if that `@rid` has an hour vertex connected to it, if not, create it and join it etc and recursively from YEAR down to SECOND. Any elegant solutions to this?